# android setvisibility gone does not release space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with one textview and two images (width fixed width, height = 48dip). When I setvisibility view.gone for one image, it does not release the space

[image]

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_subject_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:text="This is subject name"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_edit"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_subject_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_edit"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/edit_blue"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_quick_reply"/>

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:id="@+id/btn_quick_reply"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/edit_quick_reply_blue"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: Please add the XML, maybe the space is free, you're just not making use of it...

Comment: Both the picture and the xml show that the image you changed its visibility is the last image and it's space is gone

Comment: Where is the problem? What space is not released and what is the `width` of the parent `layout`?

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, i would use a `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`. something like that:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ....>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        ...>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        ...>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: He wants that the middle button moves to the right when the right one's visibility is set to gone. That's usually easier to implement with a LinearLayout. I'm open for other suggestions though.

Comment: I'm a big RelativeLayout fan too, but only if it makes sense. There is a reason why other layouts exist. And you really don't see how the ImageView moves? The TextView to the left is set to fill all unused space. To the right two ImageView. When you set img2's visibility to gone, img1 will move to the right. LinearLayout is perfect for this kind of problems. Definitely better than adding an empty view to the layout just so you have an anchor.